# How to delete the same words in each row of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
        workhours
0       0 days 01:45:13.250000000
1       0 days 04:23:56.723404255
2       0 days 07:11:01.688888888
3       0 days 06:02:48.160000000
4       0 days 06:27:57.280000000
5       0 days 07:00:26.551020408
6       0 days 09:04:01.039215686
7       0 days 08:50:11.941176470
8       0 days 07:30:59.725490196
...
```

And I just want to have the hours and not the "= days".
How can I delete this from each row?

Comment: use str.replace(pattern) in pandas

Comment: if the pattern of the data is same, `df.workhours.str.split().str[-1]` also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
import re

df["workhours"] = df["workhours"].apply(lambda x: re.sub("\d+ days ", "", x))
```

Comment: I get the error that the name "re" is not defined. what do I have to import ?

Comment: You need just to ```import re``` - I edited the answer

Comment: or use `df["workhours"].str.replace("\d+ days ", "")`